# how to enter sequence and the interval in Matlab dialog

Tags: string, matlab, dialog

In Matlab I am using a simple dialog

```
dialog1 = inputdlg('Enter sequence of bad scans:');
bad = str2num(dialog1{:});
```

to recognize outliers. However, I would prefer to have an option to eliminate whole intervals. For example `1 3-5` to include `1 3 4 5` to vector `bad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply enter: `1 3:5`.

Or, alternatively, You could use [`regexprep` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to replace '-' by ':' as shown below:

```
bad = str2num(regexprep(dialog1{:}, '-', ':'));
```